# How to render newlines in NoSQL data with a web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, firebase

How have a long string and would like to seperate some of the text with a newline.

it seems \n or \n does not work or

What is in database:

```
description: "Hello \n world"
```

When I retrieve the data I get

> Hello world

Instead of:

> Hello
>
> World

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap content in `<pre>` tag, so that will get formatted correctly on view.

```
<pre>{{description}}</pre>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QnvMo2mujIkOT96vi4A2?p=preview)

---

Other options is to use `ng-bind-html` directive + add `ngSanitize` module in app depenency

```
<p ng-bind-html="description"></p>
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/q3uTJraK3L9eFm1GATBY?p=preview)

Comment: perfect!  I was banging me head on the desk for this answer! Thank you!!

Comment: @Doopler glad to help you. Thanks :)